# What is the scope of a random seed in Python?

Tags: python, random, scope, random-seed

If I use the Python function `random.seed(my_seed)` in one class in my module, will this seed remain for all the other classes instantiated in this module?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, the seed is set for the (hidden) global `Random()` instance in the module. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html):

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the `random.Random` class. You can instantiate your own instances of`Random` to get generators that don’t share state.

Use separate `Random()` instances if you need to keep the seeds separate; you can pass in a new seed when you instantiate it:

```
>>> from random import Random
>>> myRandom = Random(anewseed)
>>> randomvalue = myRandom.randint(0, 10)
```

The class supports the same interface as the module.

Comment: Does it mean that `eval( "random.random()" )` will also honour this seed?

Comment: @Dilawar yes, `eval()` is not special here; it still uses the same namespaces and `random` is looked up from the globals you run `eval()` in, finding the same module.

Comment: Just for clarification: objects instantiated from this class will still yield different (for each object) values for the random variables.