# Is there a scope for (numpy) random seeds?

Tags: python, numpy, random, scope

My question is related to [What is the scope of a random seed in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368996/what-is-the-scope-of-a-random-seed-in-python) . 
In the case of above question, it is clarified that there is a (hidden) global `Random()` instance in the module for `random`.

1) I would like to clarify whether setting the random seed in one module will cause this to be the random seed in **other** modules and whether there are certain things to be aware of.

For instance:
Given: moduleA.py, moduleB.py

moduleA.py:

```
import random 
import moduleB
random.seed(my_seed)
moduleB.randomfct()
```

moduleB.py:

```
import random 
def randomfct():
    #do_things_using_random
```

Does moduleB also use `my_seed`, or do I have to pass the seed to moduleB.py and set it again?

2) Does the order of setting the random seed / importing play any role?

For example in `moduleA.py`:

```
import random 
random.seed(my_seed)
import moduleB
```

3) Is this also the case for setting numpy random seeds, e.g. `np.random.seed(42)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The CPython `random.py` implementation is very readable. I recommend having a look: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/random.py

Anyway, that version of python creates a global `random.Random()` object and assigns it directly to the `random` module. This object contains a `seed(a)` method which [acts as a module function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/random.py#L746) when you call `random.seed(a)`. Thus the seed state is shared across your entire program.

1) Yes. `moduleA` and `moduleB` uses the same seed. Importing `random` in `moduleA` creates the global `random.Random()` object. Reimporting it in `moduleB` just gives you the same module and maintains the originally created `random.Random()` object.

2) No. Not in the example you gave, but in general yes it can matter. You might use `moduleB` before you set the seed in `moduleA` thus your seed wasn't set.

3) Hard to tell. Much more complicated code base. That said, I would think it works the same way. The authors of numpy would really have to *try* to make it work in a different way than how it works in the python implementation.

In general, if you are worried about seed state, I recommend creating your own random objects and pass them around for generating random numbers.

Answer (score 3):

So, for answering your first question:

> Does moduleB also use my_seed, or do I have to pass the seed to moduleB.py and set it again?

Yes, it does, For example,  ran the following:

ModuleA:

```
import moduleb
import random 
random.seed(0)
my_random()
```

ModuleB

```
import random
def my_random():
    print(random.randint(0,5))
```

This will always print 3, as the seed is set.
The general rule is that the main python module that has to be run should call the random.seed() function and this creates a seed that is shared among all the imported modules.
This is only changed if you explicitly call random.seed again from some other module.

For question 2:

> Does the order of setting the random seed / importing play any role?

No it doesn't. Unless you call the random function before setting seed.

For question 3:

> Is this also the case for setting numpy random seeds, e.g. np.random.seed(42)?

So, the issue that comes with using np.random.seed() is that they are not thread safe and that's why they don't behave similarly. More details can be found at:
[This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7030595/9153399)

Answer (score 1):

In jupyter notebook, random.seed seems to have cell scope. 
For instance, random.seed(1) is needed to be specified in both two consecutive cells to get the same result with the following code:

Cell 1:

```
np.random.seed(1)
np.random.random_sample(4)
```

Cell 2:

```
np.random.seed(1)
np.random.random(4)
```

Comment: If you call np.random.random_sample(4) in cell 1 even with a global object you shouldn't expect calling it again in cell 2 to give the same results. They should be the next values produced by the RNG not repeats of previous numbers. What you should do is set the seed call 8 random numbers write them down, restart the notebook set the seed call four numbers and then 4 more in the next cell. If the second 4 numbers don't match what you wrote down than the scoping works as you suggest.

Comment: Does np.random.seed(42) have even less than cell scope? I am using random seed, then running a train_test_split function from sklearn. Then in the same cell I am running a RandomForestRegressor. If I add a second np.random.seed(42) after the train_test_split function, then i get a different score from my model. This implies that the seed is 'used up' in the first function.